# Delete list data foreach

Tags: c#, foreach

hi i have code like this

```
List<CQuizOccurrence> matchData = new List<CQuizOccurrence>();
foreach (CQuizOccurrence myQuizOccurrence in Global.quizOccurrences) 
{
    DateTime dtDatabase = (DateTime)myQuizOccurrence.occurred;
    string dt = dtDatabase.ToString();
    if (dt == dateOccur) {
        matchData.Add(myQuizOccurrence);
    }
}

foreach (CQuizOccurrence myQuizOccurrence in matchData)
{
    Global.quizOccurrences.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

i think that code will be able to ***delete 'Global.quizOccurences' data which 'dt == dateOccur'*** but i'm wrong, it's just simplely delete 'Global.quizOccurences' with index 0

how to correct it as i wish (italic & bold text)

Comment: Maybe you want to just `Global.quizOccurences.RemoveWhere(qo=>((DateTime)qo.occurred).ToString()==dateOccur);`

Comment: @Blablablaster i can't use .removeWhere property...is that available in framework 4.0?

Comment: Think it should be `RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line :

```
Global.quizOccurrences.RemoveAt(0);
```

to this :

```
Global.quizOccurrences.Remove(myQuizOccurrence);
```

Answer (score 3):

`RemoveAt()` removes the item at the specified index. In your case, you need to remove items matching a specific condition, not the items at the start of the list.

```
var itemsToRemove = Global.quizOccurrences
    .Where(q => q.occurred.ToString() == dateOccur)
    .ToList();

foreach(var quizOccurrence in itemsToRemove)
{
    Global.quizOccurrences.Remove(quizOccurrence);
}
```